# Draw surface bound by ellipse in GeoGebra

Tags: geogebra

I want to draw 3D surface in Geogebra given by f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 bounded by 3x^2+5xy+3y^2=4.I tried using polar representation but the surface does not bind with ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to show the portion of the surface `z = x² + y²` that lies above the set of all points in the `(x,y)`-plane inside the ellipse `3x² + 5x y + 3y² = 4`, then

`If(3x² + 5x y + 3y² < 4, x² + y²)`

should work, because `b(x,y) = 3x² + 5x y + 3y²` is a paraboloid opening upward, so the points inside `b(x,y) = 4` are just the ones where `b(x,y)` takes on a value smaller than 4.